# Why isn't this question closed as too localized?

Tags: discussion, question

I've seen many questions which are too localized go un-closed. For example, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/151312/8553) is much too localized. It's only ever helpful to that one guy doing that one professor's homework that one time, and is worthless to everyone else.

So I'd like to ask why the above question hasn't been closed?

Comment: `I've seen many questions which are too localized go un-closed.` ***WTF?*** That question was asked an hour ago and it's the weekend... Not saying that it should or shouldn't be closed (only checked the timestamp) but WTF...

Comment: Seems more off-topic than too localized: wants to know how to do X specific thing in C++.

Comment: @YannisRizos: This is just the most recent example- and it's commented on by enough people to have closed it.#

Comment: @DeadMG Well could you post a couple more examples? Is there a specific category / type of questions that you think survive when they shouldn't?

Answer (score 3):

When it was flagged, I decided not to close it because it seems like a fairly common homework assignment with a twist.  It also resembles very closely the same concepts behind the famous [FizzBuzz Problem a.k.a Why Can't Programmers... Program?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html).

The twist of course that the OP presented is to not use a conditional statement which seems like another really interesting variation of the FizzBuzz question that can be used by programmers to test basic programming skills in entry level applicants.

I admit there are a few problems with the question, and I would be disgusted if the users started blatantly answering homework questions, but I hold out hope that somebody can edit the question to perhaps make it a bit more generic and useful to others.

Of course this was my take on this so feel free to downvote my answer to oblivion if you feel that I am off the mark here.